# Dynamic select option not working on dynamically created fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here is my html Code:

```
    <div class="full Mtop2">
                <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="col-6 label">
                        <label>City</label>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-6-m feild">
                    <select name="selfaclcity[]" id="selfaclcity">
                        <option value=""> --- Select --- </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4-m">
                        <div class="col-4 label">
                    <label>State</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8-m feild">
                     <select name="selfaclstate[]" id="selfaclstate">
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-6-m">
                 <div class="col-7 label">
                    <label>Zip Code</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5-m feild">
                     <input type="text" id="txtfaclzipcode" value="" name="txtfaclzipcode[]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="col-6">
                <div class="col-7 label">
                    <label>Multiple Facility Owners?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5-m feild">
                    <select name="selmulti_owner[]" id="selmulti_owner" class="selmulti_owner">
                                    <option value="10"> --- Please Select --- </option>
                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="0">No</option>
                                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my Code to select states from Database:

```
 var url = "<?php echo 'inc/getstate.php' ?>";
     var getstate = "getstate";
     $.post(url,{'getstate':getstate},function(msg){
         $('#selstate').append(msg);
         $('#selfaclstate').append(msg);
         $('#selcurfaclstate').append(msg);
     });
```

Here is my code to generate dynamic input fields(.JS Page)

```
$( document ).on( "change", ".selmulti_owner", function() { 
            if($(this).val() == 1){

         var i=$('.multi_facility').length;



        var url = "../inc/getstate.php";

        var getstate = "getstate";
        $.post(url,{'getstate':getstate},function(msg){
        $('#selfaclstate'+i).html(msg);

     });

                 $html ='';
$html += '<div class="full multi_facility">';
                $html += '<div class="col-6 label">';
                $html += '<label> Additional City</label>';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '<div class="col-6-m feild">';
                $html += '<select name="selfaclcity[]" id="selfaclcity">';
                $html += '<option value=""> --- Select --- </option>';
                $html += '</select>';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '<div class="col-6-m">';
                $html += '<div class="col-6 label">';
                $html += '<label>Additional State</label>';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '<div class="col-6-m feild">';
                $html += '<select name="selfaclstate[]" id="selfaclstate">';
                $html += '<option value="NY">New York</option>';
                $html += '</select>';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '<div class="col-6-m">';
                $html += '<div class="col-7 label">';
                $html += '<label>Additional Zip Code</label>';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '<div class="col-5-m feild">';
                $html += '<input type="text" id="txtfaclzipcode" value="" name="txtfaclzipcode[]">';
                $html += '</div>';
                $html += '</div>';
$html += '</div>';
    $html += '<div class="facility_minus Mtop2"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x"></i></div>';
                $html += '</div>';
      $('.Facility_add').append($html); 
            } 
        });
```

Here is States fields are generated from my database. when i select a state its corresponding city's shown in city field and i select a city in an option its corresponding zip code shown in corresponding zip code field.
In my second step i select Multiple Facility Owners? if i select yes display some other fields. but states are not appear in state fields. Initial state it's work but dynamically generated state field its not work.
Please Help me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the flow here, or the process. Your javascript `.on( "change"` method appears to be appending more dropdowns, using IDs that have already been used in the page. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID - thats' invalid HTML. Also it's not clear what triggers the call to "getstate.php". Is it within some sort of event?

Comment: ok, i change my code to this `var i=$('.multi_facility').length;` so my fields like this `$html += '<select name="selfaclstate[]" id="selfaclstate'+i+'">';
            $html += '<option value="NY">New York</option>';
            $html += '</select>';`

Comment: how does the call to the "getstate" php get triggered? Anyway you'll need to add code into code processing the response to populate the secondary dropdowns. Or change it to work on CSS classes (shared by the different dropdowns) instead of IDs

Comment: i edit my above code, please verify.

Comment: "not work". how exactly? what happens / doesn't happen? Do you get any errors in the console? Also please update your code fully in the question including what you put in the comments above, makes it easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson now it solved. working perfectly. thanks